# Array modifier and fit to curve does not work!

Tags: modeling

I am trying to add a chain to a bezier curve but when I hit fit to curve the chain is much shorter than the curve, and when I apply the curve modifier and parent it with the bezier curve it just places the chain above the curve and stretches the chain, distorting its geometry,

I have set the origin to the volume of the chain, I've set the chain right and where the 3D cursor is but nothing seems to help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok I just added the blend file. Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: so you need to apply the scale of both your objects, otherwise it will deform the chain, but also, once done, as it will change the curve vertices radius, don't forget to bring them back to 1 (select the curve vertices and open the N panel on the right of the 3D view). Also, in your case, the Relative Offset of the Array must be on the X axis, not Y.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Im not sure how to apply the scale, and dont know what you mean by setting the curve to 1. Also If I have the relative offset on X it will array the chain sideways, not in a line as it should.

Comment: Ok, so I applied the scale to both the chain and the curve, which did the trick when it comes to fitting the length of the array to the curve length. But when I add the curve modifier and parent the chain to the curve it places it somewhere else and distorts it.

Comment: Try this: Select all the vertices and in the N panel (box that you activate with N, on the top right of the 3D view), change the radius to 1. Also put the origin of the curve at its beginning, make sure that the direction is good, if not right click > Switch Direction. Then put the object at the exact same beginning point. Rotate it in Edit mode if necessary.